# Remove Tab Spaces in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a delimited string containing tabs, and when I do `Trim` for the string it is not working. For normal space and double spaces `Trim` is working properly. Below is my code.

```
Dim arrStr    
arrStr = Split("Customer|Customer Address               |Account", "|")     
If (Trim(arrStr(1)) = "First Lane") Then
    WScript.Echo "Inside If"
End If
WScript.Echo "Outside If"
```

I tried with `LTrim`, `RTrim` and `Trim`, but nothing works. I also tried writing custom methods to trim tabs like below, but that also does not work. Any help here please?

```
Function customTrim(str)
    Dim re
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "^\t*"
    re.Multiline = False
    customTrim = re.Replace(str, "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The builtin functions `Trim`, `LTrim`, and `RTrim` don't remove all whitespace, just regular spaces, hence they won't work for your scenario.

The regular expression you have (`^\t*`) would only remove leading tabs, but your sample data seems to have trailing tabs. If you want to remove trailing tabs change the expression to `\t+$`. However, since you probably want to remove all leading/trailing whitespace I'd recommend using `^\s+|\s+$` instead. Note that you also need to set the property `Global` to `True`, otherwise only the first match would be removed. The default for the property `Multiline` is `False`, so you don't need to explicitly set that.

```
Function CustomTrim(str)
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "^\s+|\s+$"
    re.Global  = True
    CustomTrim = re.Replace(str, "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
varStr = "Customer|Customer Address                     |Account"

MsgBox CustomTrim(varStr)

Function CustomTrim(str)
  Dim re
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "\t+" '<~~ select one or more tabs
  re.Multiline = True
  CustomTrim = re.Replace(str, "")
End Function
```

You used an incorrect regex pattern - you were looking for any tab which is the beginning of string/line (^). You needed to look for one or more tabs wherever they are present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

`str=replace(str,vbTab,"")`

I *love* regex but this is simpler. It will remove leading, trailing and internal tabs. If you only want to remove some tabs, then definitely go the regex route.